# How do I package powershell advanced function args into a hashtable

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

I have a function

```
function Add-PromptSection() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [ConsoleColor]$Fore,
        [ConsoleColor]$Back,
        [Switch]$Newline,
        [Scriptblock]$Condition,
        [String]$String
    )

    $args = <something>
}
```

What I want to do is to collect the function arguments into a hashtable

```
@{ Fore=$Fore; Back=$Back; Newline=$Newline;
   Condition=$Condition; String=$String }
```

However, if the user omitted a particular argument when calling the function, I want that key to be omitted from the hashtable. The idea is that after a bit of preprocessing, I will call Write-Host with the hashtable, as `Write-Host @args`. So I don't want something like `$args["Back"] = $null` in there.

Obviously I can do this by explicitly checking each argument (actually, can I? How do I tell if the user didn't supply $Fore? Checking for $null will work, I guess, but it's not *quite* the same behaviour as `Write-Host`) but is there a more compact approach?

Comment: If you want to check if a parameter has been supplied or not, you could use `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey('MyParameterName')`.

Comment: There's an automatic variable called `$PSBoundParameters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're wanting (at least the hash table) is already being done for you by $PSBoundParameters.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you are looking for default values for your arguments. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
function Add-PromptSection() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [ConsoleColor]$Fore,
        [ConsoleColor]$Back="Red",
        [Switch]$Newline,
        [Scriptblock]$Condition,
        [String]$String
    )

    Write-Host $args
}
```

Now, the user can safely ignore providing $back in hashtable.